# Ruby read/write to file in 1 line of code

Tags: ruby, code-golf

I am kind of a newbie to Ruby, I am working out some katas and I stuck on this silly problem. I need to copy the content of 1 file to a new file in 1 line of code

First try:

```
File.open(out, 'w').write(File.open(in).read)
```

Nice, but it's wrong I need to close the files:

```
File.open(out, 'w') { |outf| outf.write(File.open(in).read) }
```

And then of course close the read:

```
File.open(out, 'w') { |outf| File.open(in) { |inf| outf.write(outf.read)) } }
```

This is what I come up with, but it does not look like 1 line of code to me :(

Ideas?

Regards,

Comment: Does FileUtils, File.copy count ?

Comment: i dont see any line breaks or semi colons.....

Comment: @matt I know, but if I have to be right to myself I will have to put some line breaks there

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways. You could simply invoke the command line for example:

```
`cp path1 path2`
```

But I guess you're looking for something like:

```
File.open('foo.txt', 'w') { |f| f.write(File.read('bar.txt')) }
```

Comment: yes, this was my second option, but how about File.read('bar.txt'), doesn't it need to close ?

Comment: you mean like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795447/rubys-file-open-and-the-need-for-f-close

Answer (score 34):

Ruby 1.9.3 and later has a

```
File.write(name, string, [offset], open_args)
```

command that allows you to write a file directly. `name` is the name of the file, `string` is what you want to write, and the other arguments are above my head.

Some links for it: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/NEWS , http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1081 (scroll to the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
File.open(out_file, "w") {|f| f.write IO.read(in_file)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
IO.binwrite('to-filename', IO.binread('from-filename'))
```

Check the ruby docs:

[IO::binwrite](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-binwrite) & [IO::binread](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-binread)