# Is there something like a null-stream in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, stream

I could use:

```
File.open('/dev/null', 'w')
```

on Unix systems, but if there is a Ruby way to achieve this, I'd like to use it. I am just looking for an I/O stream, that immediately "trashes" all writes, kind of like a null-object.

Comment: If there isn't one already, it'd be insanely easy to make one.  Just have a class with write methods that do nothing.

Comment: That should work fine on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

Comment: just found this gist https://gist.github.com/369632

Comment: @tinman sure about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is anything like a null stream in Ruby, at least in earlier versions. In that case, you must make one yourself. Depending on the methods that it will call, you will need to write
stub methods on the null stream class, like this:

```
class NullStream
   def <<(o); self; end
end
```

The above example is by no means complete.  For example, some streams may require calling the `write`, `puts` or other methods.  Moreover, some methods should be implemented by returning `self` in their methods, like `<<`, others not.

Comment: That needs to be `def <<(o); self end` to work properly (otherwise `null_stream << foo << bar` will break).

Comment: This nullifies output only on application or user level (virtual or fake streams, string IOs, etc.), not on system level (real streams, fd, device files, etc.). 
[Marc-André Lafortune's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8682009/445221) is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 83):

If you want the full behavior of streams, the best is probably to use:

```
File.open(File::NULL, "w")
```

Note that `File::NULL` is new to Ruby 1.9.3; you can use my [`backports`](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem:

```
require 'backports/1.9.3/file/null' # => Won't do anything in 1.9.3+
File.open(File::NULL, "w")          # => works even in Ruby 1.8.6
```

You could also copy the [relevant code](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master//lib/backports/1.9.3/file/null.rb) if you prefer.

Comment: That's excellent. This is how I use it:
`STDNULL = File.open(File::NULL, 'w')` then I use STDNULL every where

Answer (score 10):

There's stringIO, which I find useful when I want to introduce a dummy filestream:

```
require "stringio"
f = StringIO.new
f.gets # => nil
```

And here's some code from heckle that finds the bit bucket for both Unix and Windows, slightly modified:

```
# Is this platform MS Windows-like?
# Actually, I suspect the following line is not very reliable.
WINDOWS = RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/
# Path to the bit bucket.
NULL_PATH = WINDOWS ? 'NUL:' : '/dev/null'
```

Comment: The StringIO.new trick gets my +1 because it doesn't seem to open a file descriptor, so perhaps doesn't require explicit closing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795447/rubys-file-open-and-the-need-for-f-close

Comment: It doesn't trash input though, so has the potential to cause a memory leak depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2):

`Logger.new("/dev/null")` does the trick

Answer (score 1):

There's a gem called [devnull](https://rubygems.org/gems/devnull)

> Ruby implementation of null file (like /dev/null on Un*x, NUL on
>   Windows)

It doesn't interact with the null file, but instead has dummy methods for all the methods that IO objects implement.