# Is it bad practice to not close the file in this snippet?

Tags: ruby, file-io

Just some food for thought about how necessary it is to close the files that I opened explicitly in the code. I came from a background of programming in C and C++, and starting to navigate my way through Ruby. Thanks in advance for your feedback.

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV
script = $0

puts "Copying from #{from_file} to #{to_file}"
File.open(to_file, 'w').write(File.open(from_file).read())

puts "Alright, all done."
```

Comment: If you're just trying to copy a file, you can use [`FileUtils.cp`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Glad to know right now. Thanks!

Comment: It's bad practice to not leave fd's open in the same sense that it's bad practice not to pull your zipper up after you pee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not closing files is always bad practice unless you are using something like the `with` statement in python.

While a scripting language will usually close open files on exit, it's cleaner to do it as soon as you are done with the file - especially when writing to it.

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795447/rubys-file-open-and-the-need-for-f-close) Ruby has something similar to python's `with`:

```
File.open(from_file, 'r') do |f_in|
    File.open(to_file, 'w') do |f_out|
        f_out.write(f_in.read)
    end
end
```

Relevant docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open

Comment: That would mean I would need extra lines to grab the handles though. Or does it?

Comment: @stanigator: Why do you care (even a little bit) about adding a couple lines of code if that increases the quality of your code?

Comment: Besides that, I'm sure ruby has a simple method to copy a file that does not involve you opening either of the files manually.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I guess I'll find out in the next few days. Do both `do` in Ruby and `with` in Python allow garbage collection with the file i/o to take place automatically when the code hits `end`? I'm not familiar with Python either, and it's next on my learning bucket list after Ruby.

Comment: @stanigator No, the `do...end` here is a *block* that is passed to the `open` method, which then opens the file, then runs the block passing the file as an argument, and when the block finishes running it then closes the file.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Thanks for the complete explanation. My guess only hit the part of when the files are closed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorter version:

```
File.write to_file, File.read(from_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code (Matheus Moreira) closes files automatically:

```
File.write to_file, File.read(from_file)
```

There are no ways to close files in this code:

```
File.open(to_file, 'w').write(File.open(from_file).read())
```

I guess automatically closing too.

Comment: Didn't know I can do this too in 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good answer but it's more 'ruby' to put the output file on the outer block and use << :

```
File.open(to_file, 'w') do |f_out|
  f_out << File.open(from_file){|f| f.read}
end
```

note how you do not need the 'r' when reading.