# Should I close StringIO instances explicitly?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing some tests using [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) class and just wonder: I can close StringIO instance, since it is actually mimicking IO, but should I really bother? Should I close StringIO instances as I actually [should close files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795447/rubys-file-open-and-the-need-for-f-close)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, reads and writes go straight to the underlying string; there's no extra buffers to flush, and no OS-level resources to return.

The only reason you might want to close the StringIO is to make subsequent IOs fail or if you needed to make `closed?` return true, which could be useful if you gave that StringIO to some other component. On the other hand, if you're just going to discard the StringIO a moment later, it doesn't matter in the slightest; the garbage collector doesn't care if it's marked as open or closed.