# How to download an image file via HTTP into a temp file?

Tags: ruby, uri, net-http

I've found [good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263540/how-do-i-download-a-binary-file-over-http) of NET::HTTP for downloading an image file, and I've found [good examples](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) of creating a temp file. But I don't see how I can use these libraries together. I.e., how would the creation of the temp file be worked into this code for downloading a binary file?

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start("somedomain.net/") do |http|
    resp = http.get("/flv/sample/sample.flv")
    open("sample.flv", "wb") do |file|
        file.write(resp.body)
    end
end
puts "Done."
```

Comment: Did you submit the edit correctly? I suspect not otherwise your code seems like a direct copy of your first example.

Comment: And what happens when you replace the `open("sample.flv")...` part with the stuff you read from the Tempfile docs?

Comment: @Shadwell; this is the first example I've posted.

Comment: Okay, so maerics' question still stands then. What have you tried so far? (I assume more than just running the code from the first example and hoping it magically works!)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are more api-friendly libraries than `Net::HTTP`, for example [httparty](http://rubygems.org/gems/httparty):

```
require "httparty"

url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/DahliaDahlstarSunsetPink.jpg/250px-DahliaDahlstarSunsetPink.jpg"

File.open("/tmp/my_file.jpg", "wb") do |f| 
  f.write HTTParty.get(url).body
end
```

Comment: Thanks; I was looking for an httparty example in binary mode like this.

Comment: Considering it's an image file, you might want to set `f.binmode` before starting to write to the file.

Comment: @MariusButuc suggestion added.

Comment: add `f.close` as without it file may not get closed properly => 0B problem

Comment: `f.binmode` is already covered by the file open mode `wb`. `f.close` is redundant because the `File.open` block will always close the file see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4795782/716

Answer (score 17):

```ruby
require 'net/http'
require 'tempfile'
require 'uri'

def save_to_tempfile(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    resp = http.get(uri.path)
    file = Tempfile.new('foo', Dir.tmpdir, 'wb+')
    file.binmode
    file.write(resp.body)
    file.flush
    file
  end
end

tf = save_to_tempfile('http://a.fsdn.com/sd/topics/transportation_64.png')
tf # => #<File:/var/folders/sj/2d7czhyn0ql5n3_2tqryq3f00000gn/T/foo20130827-58194-7a9j19>
```

Comment: Interesting. I get an encoding error running this with ruby 2.0 inside Rails: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Comment: @Dogweather do then `resp.body.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")` and try the same.

Comment: The fix is adding "file.binmode".

Comment: Just a heads up, this won't work if the URL includes parameters, as eg. S3 authenticated urls.

Answer (score 10):

I like to use RestClient:

```
file = File.open("/tmp/image.jpg", 'wb' ) do |output|
  output.write RestClient.get("http://image_url/file.jpg")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Though the answers above work totally fine, I thought I would mention that it is also possible to just use the good ol' `curl` command to download the file into a temporary location. This was the use case that I needed for myself. Here's a rough idea of the code:

```rb
# Set up the temp file:
file = Tempfile.new(['filename', '.jpeg'])

#Make the curl request:
url = "http://example.com/image.jpeg"
curlString = "curl --silent -X GET \"#{url}\" -o \"#{file.path}\""
curlRequest = `#{curlString}`
```

Comment: For my case I was trying without the ['filename', '.jpeg'] array in the new tempfile and it wasn't working. Adding it made it work.

Answer (score 4):

If you like to download a file using HTTParty you can use the following code.

```
resp = HTTParty.get("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png")

file = Tempfile.new
file.binmode
file.write(resp.body)
file.rewind
```

Further, if you want to store the file in ActiveStorage refer below code.

```
object.images.attach(io: file, filename: "Test.png")
```