# Weird File.open behavior when using different closure types in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows

I started learning Chef to manage our servers and I stumbled in a very weird (in my opinion) behavior in Ruby. I do not know Ruby so this might be just a misunderstanding from my part.

The [error](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=L7THN3na) I was getting was

```
`delete': Permission denied - [some path]/metadata.json (Errno::EACCES)
```

Since I knew for sure that it was not actually about permissions, the next logical thing was to check for file locking. After digging a bit through the relevant code, I discovered that there is a method that produces a checksum for each file.

- [load_root](https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley/blob/master/lib/ridley/chef/cookbook.rb#L267)
- [file_metadata](https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley/blob/master/lib/ridley/chef/cookbook.rb#L154)
- [checksum](https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley/blob/master/lib/ridley/chef/cookbook.rb#L15)
- [md5_checksum_for_file](https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley/blob/master/lib/ridley/chef/digester.rb#L15)
- [generate_md5_checksum_for_file](https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley/blob/master/lib/ridley/chef/digester.rb#L32)
- [checksum_file](https://github.com/RiotGames/ridley/blob/master/lib/ridley/chef/digester.rb#L42)

```rb
def checksum_file(file, digest)
  File.open(file, 'rb') { |f| checksum_io(f, digest) }
end

def checksum_io(io, digest)
  while chunk = io.read(1024 * 8)
    digest.update(chunk)
  end
  digest.hexdigest
end
```

Having found that, I searched a bit and found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795447/rubys-file-open-and-the-need-for-f-close/4795561#4795561) about closing files in Ruby and it seemed that the code was actually fine... but it was not. I tried to change the method to the 
"block format" and it worked without error:

```rb
def checksum_file(file, digest)
  File.open(file, 'rb') do |f|
    checksum_io(f, digest)
  end
end
```

Can someone please explain the difference between the two versions of the code?

**-- Edit --**

It seems that this problem occurs only in Windows and maybe only when using the ruby provided by ChefDK 0.3.0 :

> ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: `the code was actually fine, but it wasn't` - been there.

Comment: both methods are identical. there is no semantic difference between `{}` and `do end` blocks

Comment: I've added more of the code in question, specifically around the `IO#read` method that is happening

Comment: According to [the pickaxe](https://pragprog.com/book/ruby4/programming-ruby-1-9-2-0), *"they have different precedences: the braces bind more tightly than the do/end pairs".* I don't know how that would explain this weird behaviour, but might give a hint to someone smarter than me to figure out. :)

Comment: @Diadistis (or anyone else who can), please edit the question and/or tag it to emphasize that this is happening on Windows.  Until somebody tries to recreate it on a POSIX OS, we don't know if this is a "ruby" question or a "ruby on windows" question.

Comment: @MattCampbell done. Have you tested the fix yourself? Does it work for you?

Comment: @Diadistis change the extension, `metadata.json` to `metadata.rb`.

Comment: @seoyoochan What difference would that make?

Comment: @CharlieHarding because Chef was built on Rub so that Chef interprets metadata.rb. Read `metadata.rb` section here. https://docs.chef.io/cookbook_repo.html

Comment: That file error is coming from the guts of the C language underbelly of Ruby's IO functionality.  As others have said, I don't believe it has anything to do with your syntax.  In cases like this I find it useful to start irb and try the simplest possible useful operation -- in this case, I would simply try opening the file without doing anything else.  I suspect this would trigger the error.  There may have been some difference in the presence or name of the file in your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer of your question

> Can someone please explain the difference between the two versions of the code?

- Block always return something so `do` end `and` and `{ ... }` dose't really matter This is just personnel programming preference.
- There are two different convention with block i'm going to dispense
  to you now and it up to you which religion you want to subscribe to.

**First religion says that**

when you have a `single line or single line block` you would use the curly braces And if you have a `multi line block` you would use `do` and `end`.

```
words.each { |word| puts word }  # single line or single line block

words.each do |word|  # multi line block
  puts word
  p 1
end
```

**Second religion says that**

If your block simply does something has side effect and you dont care about the return value you might put do and end

```
words.each do |word|
  puts word
end
```

where as if you do care about return value you would use  { ... }

```
back_words = words.map{ |word| word.reverse }
```

hope I answere your question !!!