# Testing and closing file objects while using let in ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

If I have a class like this

```
class Foo < File
  # fun stuff
end
```

and I wanted to test that it is indeed inherits from File, I could write

```
describe Foo
  let(:a_file) { Foo.open('blah.txt') }

  it "is a File" do
    expect(a_file).to be_a File
  end
end
```

My question is, will the let() take care of closing the file after the example is run? Or do I need to explicitly close the file somewhere.

Or would something like this be better,

```
it "is a File" do
  Foo.open('blah.txt') do |f|
    expect(f).to be_a File
  end
end
```

forgetting about the let() entirely?

I looked at [using let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359558/when-to-use-rspec-let) and [closing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795447/rubys-file-open-and-the-need-for-f-close) for reference, but I'm still unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to use `a_file` in just one test, then your second example is good.

```
it "is a File" do
  Foo.open('blah.txt') do |f|
    expect(f).to be_a File
  end
end
```

If you'll use `a_file` multiple times, you could do this:

```
before do 
 @file = Foo.open('blah.txt')
end

after do
  @file.close
end

it "is a File" do
  expect(@file).to be_a File
end

...
```

Comment: The before and after is a good idea. If you didn't need the file for all your specs, would let work in that case?

Comment: if you don't need it for all your tests, just use a block as in your example