# ruby read lines from string variable using character count

Tags: ruby

I have been using to split the file content based on the character count, since one of my application which doesn't support for any number of characters. So I have to split the content based on the character count and update it multiple times based on the total character count.

```
c_max = 50000
f = File.new(filename)
u_count = (c_count / c_max.to_f).ceil
i = 1
while i <= u_count do
    u_characters = f.sysread(c_max)
    # do stuffs
    i+=1
end
```

But its not working when I use strings instead of filename.

```
content=File.read(filename)
#doing some stuffs on the contents 
irb(main):006:0> content.sysread(10)
NoMethodError: undefined method `sysread' for #<String:0x7f5f2eedd368>
        from (irb):6
        from :0
irb(main):007:0>
```

Comment: Obviously, there's no method `sysread` on strings. And I have no idea what is it that you're trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: Can you use `StringIO` instead of plain `String`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to limit the number of characters [`IO#each_line`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-each_line) can help you with this e.g.

```
c_max = 100
File.open(filename) do |file|
  file.each_line(c_max) do |characters|
    # characters is now a string that is 100 characters long
    # do something with characters
  end
end
```

Or to handle a `String` you can make it a `StringIO` and `#each_line` will work too (Please note `String#each_line` will not work as it only accepts a separator (`String`) and not a character limit (`Fixnum`) this is why we need `StringIO`)

```
s = "THIS IS A STRING"
StringIO.open(s) do |strio|
  strio.each_line(2) do |characters|
    # characters is now a string that is 2 characters long
    # do something with characters
  end
end
```

So let's handle both options **Update:** (Based on comment discussion with @CarySwoveland - Thanks for pushing me further)

```
def do_stuff(line)
  # common functionality goes here 
  puts line
end

# return is a StringIO or File
# leaks file descriptor handle as you wish
def my_method(s,sep_or_char_limit=100)
  target = s.to_s # leverage a little duck typing
  target_class = File.file?(target) ? File : StringIO
  target_class.open(target) do |io|
    io.each_line(sep_or_char_limit, &method(:do_stuff))
  end
end
```

Since this uses Enumerator functionality it will also help with memory consumption since the whole `File` need not be read into memory first or the whole `String` does not need to be split into a temporary `Array`.

There is additional hidden functionality here as well. You asked for limitation by characters but this will also allow for a separator if you prefer. e.g.

```
# Using a Character Limit
my_method("THIS IS A STRING",2)
# TH
# IS
#  I
# S
# A
# ST
# RI
# NG


# Using a separator 
my_method("THIS IS A STRING",' ')
# THIS 
# IS 
# A 
# STRING
```

Comment: I like. A variant  for the body of `my_method: `(File.file?(s) ? File.open(s) : StringIO.new(s)).each_line(sep_or_char_limit, &method(:do_stuff))`. This omits your `target = s.to_s`, as I didn't understand why that's needed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `File.open` suggests that I also need to `close` where as `foreach` will close the file on block termination. the `to_s` is there for edge cases say `my_method([1,2,3,4,5],',')` this will not fail because the true definition from a documentation standpoint is simply any object that has a public `to_s` method

Comment: I considered that but the file will be closed when the method exits. I could of course begin with `target = s.to_s` and change `s` to `target` in what I suggested.

Comment: @CarySwoveland no it will be marked for Garbage Collection and once it is collected it will be auto closed at that point and who knows when that will be [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4795782/1978251) from the venerable Jorg W Mittag

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the file isn't closed right away. Without `close` would the object `StringIO.new(target)` be garbage-collected, rather than released right away? If so, and the amount of memory is significant, perhaps `target = s.to_s; obj = File.file?(target) ? File.open(target) : StringIO.new(target); obj.each_line(sep_or_char_limit, &method(:do_stuff)); obj.close`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland while it is not "Closed" closing it has no impact since closing it does not release the reference to the accumulated String we could replace this portion with `StringIO.open(target) { |strio| strio.each_line(sep_or_char_limit, &method(:do_stuff))}` which will ensure it is closed (editted for consistency sake) but will have no impact on memory consumption so it's sort six one half dozen another. I definitely understand what you are getting at but I think I still prefer the separation of concerns here from a readable and understandable standpoint.

Comment: @CarySwoveland updated just for you both `File` and `StringIO` without duplication.

Comment: In your update I like your use of `open` (didn't know about that) and the fact that you made the only difference the class, rather than the method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I aim to please and our discussion made for a better technical implementation (DRY and consistent return value). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a String object doesn't have a `sysread` method. To get the first n characters of a String object you can use String `slice(range)`:

```
content[0...10]
```

or `slice(start, length)`:

```
content[0, 10]
```